# learning powershell and trying to retrieve value from textbox

Tags: powershell, textbox, eventhandler

I'm new to this and I'm trying to build a Powershell GUI with a textbox field and use the text to query AD. Something is wrong with my code. The text is stored in variables `$textbox_HelloWorld`.Text and is called in the event handler `$button_ClickMe.Add_Click.` This does not return any results. If I replace the variable with a string then it does work. It sounds like a scope issue but I've tried using `$script:` and `$global` but neither work.

Any help appreciated.

```
# import AD module
import-module activedirectory

# Load required assemblies
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")


# Drawing form and controls
$Form_HelloWorld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form_HelloWorld.Text = "Hello World"
    $Form_HelloWorld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,240)
    $Form_HelloWorld.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $Form_HelloWorld.TopMost = $true
    $Form_HelloWorld.MaximizeBox = $false
    $Form_HelloWorld.MinimizeBox = $false
    $Form_HelloWorld.ControlBox = $true
    $Form_HelloWorld.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form_HelloWorld.Font = "Segoe UI"


# adding firstName TextBox to my form
$textbox_HelloWorld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textbox_HelloWorld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,4)
    $textbox_HelloWorld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,32)
    $textbox_HelloWorld.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $global:textbox_HelloWorld.Text = "Enter first name!"
    $Form_HelloWorld.Controls.Add($textbox_HelloWorld)
    $firstnme=$textbox_HelloWorld.Text


# adding firstName label to my form
$label_HelloWorld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_HelloWorld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(128,4)
    $label_HelloWorld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,16)
    $label_HelloWorld.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $label_HelloWorld.Text = "First Name"
    $Form_HelloWorld.Controls.Add($label_HelloWorld)

# adding lastName TextBox to my form
$Secondtextbox_HelloWorld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,38)
    $Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,32)
    $Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $global:Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Text = "Enter last name!"
    $Form_HelloWorld.Controls.Add($Secondtextbox_HelloWorld)
    $lastnme=$Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Text


# adding lastName label to my form
$Secondlabel_HelloWorld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Secondlabel_HelloWorld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(128,38)
    $Secondlabel_HelloWorld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,16)
    $Secondlabel_HelloWorld.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $Secondlabel_HelloWorld.Text = "Last Name"
    $Form_HelloWorld.Controls.Add($Secondlabel_HelloWorld)

# add a button
$button_ClickMe = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_ClickMe.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,80)
    $button_ClickMe.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_ClickMe.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_ClickMe.Text = "Click Me!"
    $button_ClickMe.Add_Click({
        $button_ClickMe.Text = "Submitted"
        $nme = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -like '$global:textbox_HelloWorld.Text' -and Surname -like '$global:Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Text*'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | out-string
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($nme , "My Dialog Box")
    })

    $Form_HelloWorld.Controls.Add($button_ClickMe)

# show form
$Form_HelloWorld.Add_Shown({$Form_HelloWorld.Activate()})
[void] $Form_HelloWorld.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking for the variable in quotes, it is seeing "$textbox_helloworld" as your variable and ".text" as a string. You need to run the command as a **SubExpression** inside the quotes via `$()`

e.g. `"$city.state"` would return "Los Angeles.state"
where `"$($city.state)"` would return "California"

Also global shouldn't be needed. This is because "Global" and "script" are for finding variables outside of the current environment. Since all of your code is in the same environment, and not in a child environment (e.g. Function or Scriptblock) you don't need to call a parent environment variable.

Here is what you want to use.

```
        $nme = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -like '$($textbox_HelloWorld.Text)' -and Surname -like '$($Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Text)*'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | out-string
```

**A final note** is that "middleCenter" is not a viable property on Textbox's, at least not on my machine. I would remove your textbox textaligns for more compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

As **[Robert Cotterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035141/robert-cotterman)** already said the filter parameter was an issue because you needed to use `subexpression` for `$TextBox.Text` value.

I also suggest you to build such string using `-f` formatting operator. Like so:

```
$button_ClickMe.Add_Click({
    $button_ClickMe.Text = "Submitted"
    $query_filter =  "GivenName -like '*{0}*' -and Surname -like '*{1}*'" -f $global:textbox_HelloWorld.Text, $global:Secondtextbox_HelloWorld.Text
    $nme = Get-ADUser -Filter $query_filter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | out-string
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($nme , "My Dialog Box")
})
```

Using `-f` operator starts with a format string, followed by one or more objects or expressions that will be converted to strings and inserted at a specified place in the format string.

The `{0}` in the format string is a format item. 0 is the index of the object whose string value will be inserted at that position. (Indexes start at 0.) If the object to be inserted is not a string, its ToString method is called to convert it to one before inserting it in the result string.

Example:

```
'{0} is an {1}' -f 'This','example'
This is an example
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you update your answer to explain what -f means?